# Scaling leaflet up from A5 to A0 in Indesign

Tags: adobe-indesign, print-design, page-layout, print-production

Is it to simply resize the PDF size, to covert all text to outlines and resize in A0 size or duplicate the Indesign file and increase all the text size manually?

Comment: I'd say rework it manually. Chances are readable type on an A5 will be *exceptionally* overpowering visually if merely scaled to an A0. But ultimatly this is dependent upon the art and any personal preference.

Comment: Thanks Scott. Yeh, I reworked it manually in the end. I wasn't sure if there was a feature which enabled me to resize the document plus the elements inside the artwork.

Answer (score 2):

Scaling everything at once holding <kbd>Ctrl/Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> (not <kbd>Alt</kbd>!) while dragging with the mouse (as @Lucian suggested) can be quite tricky. The outer bounds of your selection is often irregular and having bleeds further complicates the operation.

A trick to do it more precisely:

- Select all with <kbd>Ctrl/Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>.
- Group everything with <kbd>Ctrl/Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>.
- Cut the group with <kbd>Ctrl/Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>.
- Draw a rectangle which snaps to your document bounds.
- Paste the group into the rectangle with <kbd>Ctrl/Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>.
- Change the document size using either *Page Tool* or *File > Document Setup*.
- Scale the rectangle to the new document size while holding <kbd>Ctrl/Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>.
- Select the content of the rectangle (the group with all the content). Either click the circular symbol in the middle or select the rectangle and press <kbd>Esc</kbd>.
- Cut the content with <kbd>Ctrl/Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>.
- Delete the rectangle.
- Paste in place with <kbd>Ctrl/Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>.
- Ungroup with <kbd>Ctrl/Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>.

[image]

To scale stroke weights and effects like this, you need to make sure that *Edit > Preferences > General > Object Editing > When Scaling* is either set to *Apply to Content* with tick marks in *Include Stroke Weight* and *Include Effects* or set to *Adjust Scaling Percentage*.

Comment: Thanks Wolff! Super detailed description. I just re-worked it manually.

Answer (score 1):

Not just your text sizes will be off when you simply enlarge, but also your margins will be very big relative to the size. I'd second @Scott and say that you should rework manually. In the process, educate your customer about the fact that any extra size is additional work.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, you could try to scale this up, even without converting text to outlines.

In InDesign, select absolutely everything via <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, then simply mouse-drag from one corner of the selection to scale up.

The trick is to hold <kbd>CTRL</kbd>, <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> and <kbd>ALT</kbd> (all 3 keys pressed) while mouse dragging. This will auto adjust everything proportionally, including font size, leading, stroke weight, etc. Pretty much everything scaled proportionally.

Some adjustments may be needed depending on your artwork, but generally this should work.

Comment: Thanks! Didn't realise you could do this!